# counting number of input in a form belonging to a class

Tags: jquery

I have been using this code to count the number of input which are not empty on a form. Suddenly it decided to stop working, A work around will be appreciated. This returns zero even if i fill other text inputs of that same class.

```
 boxes= $('.unum[value!=""]').length;
           alert(boxes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = boxes = $(".unum").filter(function() {
    return (this.value.length);
}).length;
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LeshG/)

Answer (score 0):

That code will select inputs with a nonempty `value` attribute, which isn't the same as selecting inputs with no value *typed in* (a property) after the HTML was rendered.

Try this:

```
boxes = $('.unum').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() !== '';
}).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/DHGLd/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var count = 0;
$("input").each(function(){
if($(this).val()){
 count++;
}
});
```